# How to know which word is underlined?

Tags: android, underline

I can underlined a word in edittext box using this method:

```
contentText.getEditableText().setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), position, endLen, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

After i underlined the word, is there any methods that can let me know which word is underlined?This is because I need to know how many words and what is the word that had underlined. Thanks in advance for answering my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After i underlined the word, is there any methods that can let me know which word is underlined?

You already know what word is underlined. You just underlined it. Use `position` and `endLen` to retrieve the text that you underlined.

While you can call `getSpans()` later on to retrieve the `UnderlineSpan`, the `UnderlineSpan` does not contain information about its position.

Answer (score 3):

You can use 
    [getSpanEnd(Object tag)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spanned.html#getSpanEnd%28java.lang.Object%29) and [getSpanStart(Object tag)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spanned.html#getSpanStart%28java.lang.Object%29) to determine the start and end of the span. The only thing is u need to have reference to original UnderlineSpan Object.

Here is how I would do it.

```
UnderlineSpan span = new UnderlineSpan();
contentText.getEditableText().setSpan(span, 0, 5, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

Log.d("Span", "___Start___"+contentText.getEditableText().getSpanStart(span));
Log.d("Span", "___End___"+contentText.getEditableText().getSpanEnd(span));
```